Powershell to exe Start-up script, loses python's key listener focus
I'm trying to implement a Powershell start-up script, which calls a python file. When the shell calls my python file it never has focus. When I go into the start-up folder and run the script myself, it works fine but when it's run as part of the start-up process the key listener doesn't work.
I've tried many things to get my project running headless, such as running as elevating privileges, changing keylisteners in python, installing python modules that should get focus on the window, opening the file in a subprocess, opening it in a completely new shell.
As it works normally when I manually run the .exe there's clearly something I'm missing and google has been hopeless.
Write-Host "starting docker"

$user = [Environment]::UserName

Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Docker Desktop.exe"

$file_path = "C:\Users\${user}\OneDrive\Desktop\teia\windows\"


   # Check if Docker is ready
   function DockerReady {
       try {
           $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri http://localhost:2375/_ping -UseBasicParsing
           return $response -eq "OK"
       } catch {
           return $false
       }
    }
     
    # Wait for Docker
    do {
        Write-Host "Waiting for Docker to be ready..."
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 3
    } until (DockerReady)

Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList "-NoExit", "-Command", "docker run --rm -it --env ACCEPT_LICENSE=true --publish 1080:1080 tts-standalone"


Write-Host "Starting Teia"
Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList "-NoExit", "-Command", "conda run --name teia python '$file_path\run-on-startup.py' '$file_path'"


Write-Host -NoNewLine "Application initialised, press any key to exit..."
$null = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey('NoEcho, IncludeKeyDown')```


Try adding a command to set focus in your $profile script.

If you want to run this as a startup script like when the Windows login is session is started.
move this script to shell:startup folder it will automatically executes if you want to execute as a elevation make a bat script and add a path "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" your_script_path.
